# Changing screen resolution using xorg.conf file

Tags: nvidia, xorg, xrandr, xserver

I recently (today) installed Nvidia graphic drivers on my laptop, I followed the instruction on the tutorial and generated a xorg.conf file using `nvidia-xconfig`. I have am using a laptop and have plugged an external montior to it, The external monitor's resolution is fine however the main laptop screen has gone to 4:3 resolution. I have no idea what's in the `xorg.conf` file, I have never seen anything like this, can anyone help me changing the screen resolution back to 16:9, 1366x768.

Here is the xorg.conf file.

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 390.48  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-07)  Thu Mar 22 01:07:32 PDT 2018


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "layout"
    Screen      0  "nvidia" 0 0
    Inactive       "intel"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "keyboard"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       60.0 - 100.0
    VertRefresh     60.0 - 100.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "intel"
    Driver         "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    Device         "nvidia"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "PrefLevelSrc=0x2222"
    Option         "TripleBuffer" "True"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "nvidia-auto-select"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "intel"
    Device         "intel"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
EndSection
```

Comment: What is external monitor resolution? Is it 4:3? Do you have desktop mirrored to have the same picture on both screens? If you have mirrored picture than the resolution will be the same on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so after scrounging the web, this is the solution I came up with. 
I was using the manually generated `xorg.conf` file by using `nvidia-xconfig`. Which wasn't generating the correct config. This is what finally worked for me.

Press `ctrl+alt+f2` (or whatever key combination you use to get into command line mode)

Login as the administrator.

If you're using `GDM` like me go ahead and stop the process, using `service gdm stop`.

Check if your `X-server` is running or not. Use `ps -C Xorg` and then kill the process. `kill -9 PID`

Use `Xorg -configure` which will generate `xorg.conf.new`

now simply move the `.new` file to the `/etc/X11/` directory, using 

`mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

now restart the `GDM`
`service gdm start`

And you're done.