# PC doesn't wake up after suspend mode

Tags: suspend, intel-graphics, gpu

When I suspend my PC and I try to wake it up again, the only thing I get is a blank black screen.
I figured out that I can solve this problem by switching my graphic card from nvidia to intel. However I need the performances of the nvidia card, then I would like to find another way to solve it.

Comment: What laptop model, CPU and nVidia GPU do you have?

Answer (score 0):

**For problems with 'Suspend'.**

- Add the repositories. Run in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

- Install the latest driver (preferably through the gui 'Additional drivers'). Run in terminal:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

and go to 'Additional drivers' tab and install the latest nvidia driver.

[image]

- Install lightdm. Run in terminal:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

- When asked asked to choose, choose lightdm.
- If lightdm is already installed. Run in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

- When asked asked to choose, choose lightdm.
- Reboot.
  This worked for me. Hope this works for you also.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

After installing nVidia proprietary drivers and running `nvidia-settings` check you have these similar files setup:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

**Note:** I may have hand crafted some of these entries but it was done so long ago I forget.

An additional, but probably unnecessary check is for this file:

```
$ cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf/nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf`

# This xorg.conf.d configuration snippet configures the X server to
# automatically load the nvidia X driver when it detects a device driven by the
# nvidia-drm.ko kernel module.  Please note that this only works on Linux kernels
# version 3.9 or higher with CONFIG_DRM enabled, and only if the nvidia-drm.ko
# kernel module is loaded before the X server is started.

Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    MatchDriver    "nvidia-drm"
    Driver         "nvidia"
EndSection
```

If needing help using `nvidia-settings`, post comment below and I will dig up some google search links.

Comment: I've installed nvidia-drivers-418, but I can't find the xorg.config in /etc/X11.

Comment: I've read problems with `418` over last few days. Personally I'm using `384` and it's been very stable. Either way you need to run `nvidia-settings` once and save the configuration, or see this Q&A for using `nvidia-xconfig` which might work better: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023275/changing-screen-resolution-using-xorg-conf-file There are many many questions in Ask Ubuntu with nVidia configuration questions that do not have answers. They date back to the year 2012 up to today.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by installing 396 nvidia driver. Indeed you were right, with the 418 there are some problems.